# Bot framework Directline -Change Bot name Run time using node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, direct-line-botframework

Is it possible to change the name of the bot during runtime. Current the name which i have added in portal is getting displayed under bot message. Is it possible to update it in run time using node.js rather than displaying the name configured in portal.

Comment: Which channel? If you're using webchat, you can supply a bot.name to BotChat.App().   Most channels do not allow changing the bot's display name.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the **display name** of the bot, in bot's settings page. Following is a screenshot where you can do this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am trying to change bot name using node.js code (bot service). Please help.